# Swift - How can I override an extension method in a concrete subclass

Tags: ios, swift, access-control, swift-extensions

I have an extension on UIView implementing a protocol

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
  var property : Int
}
    extension UIView : SomeProtocol {
      var property : Int {
        get {
          return 0
        }
        set {
          // do nothing
        }
      }
    }
```

in a concrete subclass I want to override this extension method:

```
class Subclass : UIView, SomeProtocol {
  var _property : Int = 1
  var property : Int {
    get { return _property}
    set(val) {_property = val}
  }
}
```

I set breakpoints and see that the extension method is called and not the concrete subclass method:

```
var subclassObject = Subclass()

someObject.doSomethingWithConcreteSubclassObject(subclassObject)

// other code;

fun doSomethingWithConcreteSuclassObject(object : UIView) {
  var value = object.property // always goes to extension class get/set
}
```

Comment: I've also tried adding override but the superclass doesn't have this property

Comment: Wich Swift version are you using? Here with Swift 1.2 and Xcode 6.3.1 I get the following compile time error when you try to override the _extension_ property: "Declarations from extensions cannot be overridden yet" ... and _yet_ suggests me that they will be in the future.

Comment: Interesting, so it looks like this feature is coming in a future release.

Comment: Apparently so. This problem arose because it isn't possible to define a function returning an object of specific type implementing a protocol interface. In objective-c this was possible

Comment: Tried this with swift 2.0, seems to compile fine if you have the `override` but still refers to the `extensions` values and not the subclass.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As [others have noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29893123/swift-how-can-i-override-an-extension-method-in-a-concrete-subclass#comment47911519_29893123), Swift does not (yet) allow you to override a method declared in a class extension. However, I'm not sure whether you'll ever get the behavior you want even if/when Swift someday allows you to override these methods.

Consider how Swift deals with protocols and protocol extensions. Given a protocol to print some metasyntactic variable names:

```
protocol Metasyntactic {
    func foo() -> String
    func bar() -> String
}
```

An extension to provide default implementations:

```
extension Metasyntactic {
    func foo() -> String {
        return "foo"
    }

    func bar() -> String {
        return "bar"
    }
}
```

And a class that conforms to the protocol:

```
class FooBar : Metasyntactic {
    func foo() -> String {
        return "FOO"
    }

    func bar() -> String {
        return "BAR"
    }
}
```

Swift will use *dynamic dispatch* to call the appropriate implementations of `foo()` and `bar()` based on each variable's *runtime type* rather than on the type inferred by the compiler:

```
let a = FooBar()
a.foo()  // Prints "FOO"
a.bar()  // Prints "BAR"

let b: Metasyntactic = FooBar()
b.foo()  // Prints "FOO"
b.bar()  // Prints "BAR"
```

If, however, we extend the protocol further to add a new method:

```
extension Metasyntactic {
    func baz() -> String {
        return "baz"
    }
}
```

And if we override our new method in a class that conforms to the protocol:

```
class FooBarBaz : Metasyntactic {
    func foo() -> String {
        return "FOO"
    }

    func bar() -> String {
        return "BAR"
    }

    func baz() -> String {
        return "BAZ"
    }
}
```

Swift will now use *static dispatch* to call the appropriate implementation of `baz()` based on the type inferred by the compiler:

```
let a = FooBarBaz()
a.baz()  // Prints "BAZ"

let b: Metasyntactic = FooBarBaz()
b.baz()  // Prints "baz"
```

Alexandros Salazar has [a fantastic blog post explaining this behavior in depth](https://nomothetis.svbtle.com/the-ghost-of-swift-bugs-future), but suffice it to say that Swift only uses dynamic dispatch for methods declared in the original protocol, *not* for methods declared in protocol extensions. I imagine the same would be true of class extensions, as well.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question has been asked a while ago. But this will be handy for someone who looking for an easier way. There is a way of overriding an extension methods. I know its bit hacky but it does the job beautifully.

If you declare your protocol with `@objc`

```
@objc protocol MethodOverridable {
   func overrideMe()
}
```

**In Extension**

```
extension MainClass: MethodOverridable {
     func overrideMe() {
        print("Something useful")
     } 
}
```

**Subclass** - You can able to override it in your subclass. It works like a magic. Well, not really when adding `@objc` it exposes your `protocol to Objective-C` and its `Runtime`. That allows your subclass to override.

```
 class SubClass: MainClass {
     override func overrideMe() {
          print("Something more useful")
      }  
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5

```
class Class
{
    @objc dynamic func make() { print("make from class") }
}

class SubClass: Class {}

extension SubClass {
    override func make() {
        print("override")
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this adds any value that is not present in the accepted answer.

Comment: in the accepted answer doesn't mention dynamic

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can override property for 2nd super class property. For example, you can access `UIView` property by making extension to the `UILabel` wanting to override `frame` property of `UIView`. This sample works for me in Xcode 6.3.2

```
extension UILabel {

     override public var frame: CGRect {

         didSet {
             println("\(frame)")
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this through normal means.

It's in Apple's docs that you can't override a method in an extension in a subclass.

Also, extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot override existing functionality.

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html

Answer (score -3):

I think you forgot to override the superclass property in your subclass:

```
class Subclass : UIView {
    var _property : Int = 1
    override var property : Int {
        get { return _property}
        set(val) {_property = val}
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that as well. It gets a syntax error : " Property does not override any property from its superclass"

Comment: That's weird. Seems like your subclass can't access the super's property. Are they declared in the same source file? You might have to explicitly declare public.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109006/can-you-override-between-extensions-in-swift-or-not-compiler-seems-confused

Comment: The property isn't defined in super. The property is defined in a protocol

Comment: Since the property belongs to the protocol: is there a reason to introduce hierarchy? You could just have your class conform to the protocol without the subclassing.