# Issue with the call hierarchy of a swift protocol extension

Tags: swift, protocols

I've implemented a little wrapper for Alamofire's reachability. Now I ran into an issue with a subclass not receiving notifications.

As dfri added in a comment, the problem can be described as **a superclass method invoked by a subclass instance does not see an overridden subclass method if it is placed in an extension**.

Thanks for his excellent gist showing the reproducible problem with the usual foo/bar: https://gist.github.com/dfrib/01e4bf1020e2e39dbe9cfb14f4165656

The protocol & extension logic:

```
protocol ReachabilityProtocol: class {    
    func reachabilityDidChange(online: Bool)
}

extension ReachabilityProtocol {

    func configureReachabilityManager() {
        // triggered externally:
        rechabilityManager?.listener = { [weak self] status in
            self?.reachabilityDidChange(online)
        }
    }

    func reachabilityDidChange(online: Bool) {
        // abstract, implement in subclasses
    }

}
```

Now ViewController **A** adopts this protocol and implements the method:

```
class A: UIViewController, ReachabilityProtocol {

    func reachabilityDidChange(online: Bool) {
        debugPrint("123")
    }

}
```

Working until here, prints `123`.

ViewController **B** is a subclass and overrides the method from **A**:

```
class B: A {

    override func reachabilityDidChange(online: Bool) {
        super.reachabilityDidChange(online)
        debugPrint("234")
    }

}
```

Working, too. Prints now `234` and `123` upon notification.

Now the tricky part, in terms of structuring the code, the overriden method got moved into an own extension inside of **B** (same swift file as class **B**):

```
class B: A {
...
}

// MARK: - Reachability Notification
extension B {

    override func reachabilityDidChange(online: Bool) {
        super.reachabilityDidChange(online)
        debugPrint("234")
    }

}
```

Now **B**'s `reachabilityDidChange()` isn't called anymore. Output is just `123`.

To check the logic I even tried to remove the `override` keyword: the compiler immediately complains about needing it.

So from what I can say the call hierarchy is correct. Visibility too.

**Subsumption: If the method overridden is placed into it's own extension, it's not visible/invoked anymore but the compiler still requires the `override` keyword.**

That's something I didn't came across yet, or it's me working to long on the same project today..

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Overriding superclass methods in extensions: only allowed for Objective-C compatible methods

First of all we note that you can only override a superclass method in an extension of a subclass if the method is Objective-C compatible. For classes deriving from `NSObject`, this is true for all instance methods (which is true here, as `UIViewController` derives from `NSObject`). This is covered in e.g. the following Q&A:

- [Can you override between extensions in Swift or not? (Compiler seems confused!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109006/can-you-override-between-extensions-in-swift-or-not-compiler-seems-confused)

---

### Enforcing dynamic dispatch via Objective-C runtime

Now, from [Interoperability - Interacting with Objective-C APIs - Requiring Dynamic Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html), we note the following

> When Swift APIs are imported by the Objective-C runtime, *there are no
>   guarantees of dynamic dispatch* for properties, methods, subscripts, or
>   initializers. The Swift compiler may still devirtualize or inline
>   member access to optimize the performance of your code, bypassing the
>   Objective-C runtime.
>
> You can use the `dynamic` modifier to *require that access to members be
>   dynamically dispatched through the Objective-C runtime*.

Moreover, from [The Language Ref. - Declarations - Declaration Modifyers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html) we read

> `dynamic` (modifier)
>
> Apply this modifier to any member of a class that can be represented
>   by Objective-C. When you mark a member declaration with the `dynamic`
>   modifier, access to that member *is always dynamically dispatched using
>   the Objective-C runtime.* Access to that member is never inlined or
>   devirtualized by the compiler.
>
> Because declarations marked with the `dynamic` modifier are dispatched
>   using the Objective-C runtime, they’re implicitly marked with the `objc`
>   attribute.

**Enforcing dynamic dispatch for `reachabilityDidChange(...)` in `A`**

Hence, if you add the `dynamic` modifier to method `reachabilityDidChange(...)` in your superclass `A`, then access to `reachabilityDidChange(...)` will always be dynamically dispatched using the Objective-C runtime, and hence find and make use of the correct overridden `reachabilityDidChange(...)` method in the class `B` extension, for instances of `B`. Hence,

```
dynamic func reachabilityDidChange(online: Bool) { ... }
```

in `A` will fix the above.

---

Below follows a more minimal example of your issue above, redeemed by demanding dynamic dispatch via obj-c runtime for method `foo()` in class `A` (equivalent to your method `reachabilityDidChange(...)` in class `A`).

```
import UIKit

protocol Foo: class {
    func foo()
}

extension Foo {
    func foo() { print("default") }
}

class A: UIViewController, Foo {
    dynamic func foo() { print("A") } // <-- note dynamic here
    func bar() { self.foo() }  
            /*          \
                   hence, foo() is dynamically dispatched here, and for
                   instances where "self === B()", this is correctly
                   resolved as the foo() in the extension to B          */
}

class B : A { }

extension B {
    override func foo() {
        super.foo()
        print("B")
    }
}

let a = A()
a.bar() // A

let b = B()
b.bar() // A B
        /* or, only "A" if not using dynamic dispatch */
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you very much @dfri! While I am basically aware of dynamic vs. static dispatch, the given code slipped through code review before commit: Silently "failing" (while being logically correct due to optimization) but requiring the keyword ```override``` is a dangerous thing:  Even though I need to use dynamic dispatch with e.g. Realm properties, I overlooked it in conjunction with an UIViewController superclass subclass extension. Looks like the author of SwiftBond ran into some dispatch issues, too (but not exactly the same problem): http://www.openradar.me/23067007