# Cannot override method with a custom class return type

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, overriding

Is there any method i can use to override a method which returns custom class? When i tried to override any method with a custom class as a return type, Xcode throws me an error

Below are my codes:

```
class CustomClass {
  var name = "myName"
}

class Parent: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    methodWithNoReturn()
    print(methodWithStringAsReturn())
    methodWithCustomClassAsReturn()
  }

}

extension Parent {

  func methodWithNoReturn() { }
  func methodWithStringAsReturn() -> String { return "Parent methodWithReturn" }
  func methodWithCustomClassAsReturn() -> CustomClass {
    return CustomClass()
  }

}


class Child: Parent {

  override func methodWithNoReturn() {
    print("Can override")
  }

  override func methodWithStringAsReturn() -> String {
    print("Cannot override")
    return "Child methodWithReturn"
  }

  override func methodWithCustomClassAsReturn() -> CustomClass {
    return CustomClass()
  }

}
```

The error is when overriding this method:

> func methodWithCustomClassAsReturn() -> CustomClass

with error message:

> Declarations from extensions cannot be overridden yet

Comment: Similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109006/can-you-override-between-extensions-in-swift-or-not-compiler-seems-confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No reason other than the compiler doesn't support it yet. To override a method defined in an extension to the superclass, you must declare it ObjC-compatible:

```
extension Parent {
    func methodWithNoReturn() { }
    func methodWithStringAsReturn() -> String { return "Parent methodWithReturn" }

    @objc func methodWithCustomClassAsReturn() -> CustomClass {
        return CustomClass()
    }   
}

// This means you must also expose CustomClass to ObjC by making it inherit from NSObject
class CustomClass: NSObject { ... }
```

The alternative, without involving all the ObjC snafus is to define these methods in the `Parent` class  (not inside an extension):

```
class Parent: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    methodWithNoReturn()
    print(methodWithStringAsReturn())
    methodWithCustomClassAsReturn()
  }

  func methodWithNoReturn() { }
  func methodWithStringAsReturn() -> String { return "Parent methodWithReturn" }
  func methodWithCustomClassAsReturn() -> CustomClass {
    return CustomClass()
  }

}
```

Comment: Nice and straight forward answer. Thanks!