# Swift 'open' keyword & overridable method/properties in extension?

Tags: ios, swift, syntax, swift-extensions

With introduction of `open` keyword in Swift 3.0 ([What is the 'open' keyword in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38947101/what-is-the-open-keyword-in-swift)).

Note: Limited to extensions on `NSObject` derived classes or `@objc` attributed method/properties.

Code which declared and used `public` (`class`) methods/properties in extension *across* modules/frameworks broke, as `public` is no longer means 'overridable' outside of defining module.

Example:

```
public extension UIManagedDocument {

    public class func primaryDocumentName() -> String {
        return "Document"
    }

    public class func primaryStoreURL() -> URL {
        let documentsURL = FileManager.default.userDocumentsURL
        return URL(fileURLWithPath: self.primaryDocumentName(), isDirectory: false, relativeTo: documentsURL)
    }

    public class func primaryModelName() -> String? {
        return "Model"
    }

}
```

- Original proposal ([SE-0117](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0117-non-public-subclassable-by-default.md)) is focused on subclassing and doesn't mention extensions.
- Currently extensions do not support `open` keyword (you can't write `open extension NSObject` as well as `open func Method()`)

**Question**: Is there workaround to be able override extension provided methods/properties *across* modules/frameworks?

Comment: Is this really related to the new open vs public access modes? Unless I am mistaken, you cannot override methods declared in extensions anyway, neither in Swift 2 nor in Swift 3).

Comment: You right for *pure* swift classes, but one can on NSObject derived classes as well as with `@objc` attributed methods/properties. ([Can you override between extensions in Swift or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109006/can-you-override-between-extensions-in-swift-or-not-compiler-seems-confused#27109202))

Comment: I see, thanks. (Perhaps you can add that information to the question).

Comment: And thanks for reminding me of my own answer :)

Answer (score 9):

Unless I am mistaken, you *can* declare the extension methods as
`open` in your framework if you just omit the `public` keyword
in the extension declaration:

```
extension UIManagedDocument {

    open class func primaryDocumentName() -> String {
        return "Document"
    }
    // ...
}
```

And then (for `NSObject` subclasses or `@objc` members) you can override the method
in your custom subclass in the main application (or in any module):

```
class MyManagedDocument: UIManagedDocument {

    override class func primaryDocumentName() -> String {
        return "MyDocument"
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I can't omit `public` word, as extension is declared in another module (shared framework), and concrete subclass is implemented in the dependant target (app/extension).

Comment: @Nocross:  Actually I just tested that and it worked for me. `extension UIManagedDocument {}` is in a framework and `class MyManagedDocument: UIManagedDocument {}` in the main app.

Comment: You are right it works. But what bothers me is that this way we are relying on swift 'inference' logic, which is at least unstable, as well as may be implementation specific for different IDEs

Comment: @Nocross: I don't think this is IDE related. And note that you removed the public keyword in your solution as well.

Comment: A nuance is a bit different. I omitted it, as protocol conformance extension also conforms to access modifiers from protocol.

Comment: @Nocross: As I understand it, the default access level of an extension is the access level of the class itself (in this case: open).

Answer (score 3):

- 'Protocol-oriented' - declare *protocol* with desired methods/properties then refactor your extension for *protocol* compliance.
- 'Traditional' - implement intermediate (abstract) subclass with desired methods/properties.

Protocol example:

```
protocol PrimaryDocument {
    static func primaryDocumentName() -> String

    static func primaryStoreURL() -> URL

    static func primaryModelName() -> String?
}

extension UIManagedDocument : PrimaryDocument {

    open class func primaryDocumentName() -> String {
        return "Document"
    }

    open class func primaryStoreURL() -> URL {
        let documentsURL = FileManager.default.userDocumentsURL
        return URL(fileURLWithPath: self.primaryDocumentName(), isDirectory: false, relativeTo: documentsURL)
    }

    open class func primaryModelName() -> String? {
        return "Model"
    }

}
```